# Take maximum time during update left join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, left-join

I am doing an update left join on ID and receiver.

```
Left table
Id | Receiver | Order Time | guid | item
12 | abc      | 12:35      | NULL | NULL


Right table
Id | Receiver | Time taken | guid  | item
12 | abc      | 50seconds  | yuhb2 | 0
12 | abc      | 189seconds | vef3  | 2
```

How can I make the query to pick the record with max time taken?

```
update tableA a left join TableB b
ON  a.ID=b.ID
AND    a.receiver = b.receiver
set
a.items= b.items
where a.guid is null;
```

Expected output :

```
Left table
Id | Receiver | Order Time | guid | item
12 | abc      | 12:35      | vef3 |  2
```

Comment: In your right table you should have a primary key column & another column is for the reference of left table (which is Id column you showed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added another column (`id_primary`) in right_table. **To get the maximum use this subquery (`select id_primary from right_table order by time_taken desc limit 1`) at end**

```
 update left_table a left join right_table b
    ON  a.id= b.id
    set
    a.item= b.item,
    a.guid= b.guid
    where a.guid is null
    and b.id_primary = (select id_primary from right_table order by time_taken desc limit 1 )
```